# React-Native fetch JSON from rest service and store it as an array in state

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fetch

Hello people on StackoverFlow,

I'm developing a backend (Laravel) and a frontend (React-Native). The problem is on the frontend, where I'm trying to assign the JSON response to the state. But for some reason I can't set the "this.state.data" to be an array as it always turns out to be a string and instead of an object I get one character at a time.

I want to set the data to be an array of all the routes from the API response.

React-Native code: (OBS: URL REMOVED DUE TO SERVER IS IN DEVELOP MODE)

```
async getData() {
var token =  await AsyncStorage.getItem("token");
this.setState({ "token": token });

fetch('myurl', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    token: this.state.token
  })
}).then((response) => {

    if (response != null) {
      //console.log(response.json());
      console.log(response);

      this.setState({
        //data: response._bodyInit,
        data: JSON.stringify(response._bodyInit),
        loading: false
      });
    }
    return this.state.data;
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

}

The URL response structure looks like this:

```
{
    routes: [
      {
        id: '15',
        uuid: '26-10-2018',
        start_address: 'Krogshøj Alle 3',
        end_address: 'Lindevangs Alle 16',
        arrival: '27-10-2018 10:00',
      },
      ...
      ]
 }
```

If I hardcode the data like this, it works.

```
this.setState({
  data: 
    [
      {
        id: '15',
        uuid: '26-10-2018',
        start_address: 'Krogshøj Alle 3',
        end_address: 'Lindevangs Alle 16',
        arrival: '27-10-2018 10:00',
      },
    ]
});
```

This is where I use the data:

```
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Toolbar
      isHidden={phase !== 'phase-0'}
      onBackPress={this.onBackPressed}
    />

    <FlatList
      key={item => item.id}
      data={this.state.data}
      dataExtra={{ phase, opacityOfSelectedItem }}
      keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      renderItem={this.renderItem}
    />

  </View>
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fetch('myurl', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    token: this.state.token,
  }),
})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    this.setState({
      data: data.routes,
      loading: false,
    });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks for pointing that out. But for some reason the response in react-native looks like this: { type: 'default',
  status: 200,
  ok: true,
  statusText: undefined,
  headers: 
   { map: 
      { 'content-type': 'application/json',
        date: 'Sat, 27 Oct 2018 21:33:58 GMT',
        'content-encoding': 'gzip',
        'content-length': '992',
        vary: 'Accept-Encoding,User-Agent',
        'x-powered-by': 'PHP/7.1.23',
        'x-ratelimit-limit': '60' } },
  url: ' myurl',
  _bodyInit: '{"routes":[{"id":15,"uuid":"bdc31630-d7db-11e8-b45f-d76be65679f3"...

Comment: When im using Postman to call the API it returns as I stated in my question.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! Guess I need to work some more with react-native to really catch this. But again thanks, you are a life saviour.